# Getting an error with syntax getting a JSON file

Tags: python, django, api

I'm having a problem building a Twitter random quotes generator API. I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-deploy-twitter-bots-python-tweepy-pythonanywhere

But I get an error that he doesn't have. This is the code:

```
import requests 

api_key = '*****' 
api_url = 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com'

headers = {'afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc' : 
api_key, 'http://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com' : 
api_url}

# The get method is called when we 
# want to GET json data from an API endpoint
quotes = requests.get(quotes = requests.get(api_url, 
headers=headers)

print(quotes.json())
```

And this is the error:

```
File "twitter_bot.py", line 12
print(quotes.json())

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?? (I put *** on the key on purpose, I know the proper key is supposed to go there)

Thank you!

Comment: *What* syntax error? Where?

Comment: What are you doing here with `requests.get(quotes=...)`, it looks as if you did not specify an endpoint?

Comment: sorry @DanielRoseman just updated it

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket after `headers=headers)`, but that being said, it is still very *odd* what you are doing.

Comment: If you get a SyntaxError and you don't spot it in the actual line, check the line before it. Also, count your closing parentheses in the line above it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you were right, now I don't have the syntax error anymore, but an Invalid header name. 

It's just that I have no clue of what I'm doing, just trying to follow the tutorial and understand step by step...

Comment: your dict `headers` is strange - you use `'afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc'` as header's name. Better check code in tutorial. It uses headers `'X-Mashape-Key'`, etc.

Comment: @furas   This is what I get from the RapidAPI and it's nothing like the tutorial...

  "X-RapidAPI-Host": "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc"
  }
)

Comment: and you should use it as `api_url = "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com"` and `api_key = "afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc" `. And rather don't change `headers = {'X-Mashape-Key' : api_key, 'X-Mashape-Host' : api_url}`

Comment: I check tutorial and I also don't see any `"X-RapidAPI-Host"` and `"X-RapidAPI-Key"` - but maybe `RapidAPI` changed its code and now it uses these names so you will have to use them too. `headers = {X-RapidAPI-Host' : api_key, 'X-RapidAPI-Key' : api_url}`

Comment: @furas Changed everything and now when I activate it does nothing and when I stop the program with ctrl+c I get a huge list that ends with:     sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt. 

What am I missing now? This is getting way harder than expected --'

Answer (score 0):

You have a copy-and-paste error; somehow you've put `quotes = requests.get(` twice.

It should just be:

```
# The get method is called when we 
# want to GET json data from an API endpoint
quotes = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

print(quotes.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial is not so old but it seems it is already out of date.

Using example from [RapidAPI documentation (for Random Famous Quotes API)](https://rapidapi.com/andruxnet/api/random-famous-quotes) I created Python's code which gives some information from server (but still not quotes)

```
import requests 

url = "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com/?count=10&cat=famous"

headers={
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc",
}

quotes = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(quotes.text)
#print(quotes.json())
```

Result:

```
{"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}
```

The same for `POST`

```
import requests 

url = "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com/?count=10&cat=famous"

headers={
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "afd9cbe77emshf06f5cb2f889689p1ca1c3jsne6e79ad808cc",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

quotes = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print(quotes.text)
#print(quotes.json())
```

Result:

```
{"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}
```

---

It still need some work to get quotes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: to make something more I would have to subscribe this API but it asked for credit card.